# "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" for an existing file

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate through some directories I have to return the total size of the folder. However, I get this error

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

for one of the files in one of the subdirectories in my folder after running the function in the code. Why does this error occur, even though my function is iterating through a folder, so the file must exist?

```
def get_size(folder): 
    folder_size = 0
    for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files: 
            filename = os.path.join(path, file)
            folder_size += os.path.getsize(filename)
    return folder_size
```

Comment: Time passes between the time you find the path and the time you check its size.  During that time, the path can be removed.  The path *was* valid, but that doesn't mean it *is* valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A likely cause of this error during a walk is encountering a "dangling" symbolic link, i.e. the link target does not exist.

To work around this issue, decide what you want to do with dangling links:

- Ignore them?  You can use `os.path.islink` to check if a file is a link.
- Use `lstat` instead of `stat`, this gives the size of a link as the length of the target, rather than trying to resolve the link.  You should replace the `os.path.getsize(filename)` with `os.lstat(filename).st_size`.

Comment: I have a large directory of folders I want to extract this data for. Would a potential fix be using something like inserting an `if` statement testing `os.path.exists(path)` before `folder_size += os.path.getsize(filename)`?

Comment: @ec197, you still have a race condition that way -- it can exist when you run `os.path.exists()`, but not when you try to call `getsize()`. Better to just handle the exception.

Comment: Although race conditions are possible, I really doubt that is the underlying issue here.  Just using try/except doesn't address races completely anyway (the filesize can change during the walk, for example, so that `folder_size` computed is incorrect).

Comment: @wim `lstat` worked! new to python so this had really been frustrating me but thanks so much to everyone!!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy @wim trying to understand this issue further -- so in this case the race condition would essentially occur if the file were to disappear at some point between when I call `os.path.exists()` and when I call `os.path.getsize()`?

Comment: I agree that the race condition isn't likely to be the underlying condition that caused the question to be asked in the first place, but it's still bad form to leave them in when trying to build correct/robust code. @emillyrock, ...and correct, that's exactly the case. If someone were running `rm -rf` on a directory as you were processing it, there we are. Whereas if you just do one call and handle the exception if it fails, you don't *have* two separate calls between which you're depending on state not to change; you treat the exception as `os.path.exists()` returning False.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  My point was if you are expecting race conditions and you have to handle them robustly, then you have a lot more to worry about here than this one LBYL/EAFP choice.